# I cannot print or export Adobe XML-Form files

Tags: pdf, xml, forms, print-to-pdf

I have PDFCreator and "PrimoPDF" installed, as well as some other print software.
Now I own Adobe Acrobat and used it to save content in an Adobe XML-Form file.
Now I want to flatten that file, as Acrobat gives me an error, if I try to merge it with other (static) files.

The problem: 
Even though it's supposed to work to "flatten" a file by printing (as far as I heard) - **I even use the built-in print button**, I can't.

My goal after merging and cutting out pages is to have one PDF that I can upload to HelloFax.

My whole workflow is virtualized and time-sensitive, so can't get around this via paper...

**My error in PrimoPDF:**

> PDF Conversion Failed: -8

**My error in PDFCreator:**

> ERROR: undefined OFFENDING COMMAND: eexec STACK: /quit
>   -dictionary-
>   -mark

Any idea what could cause this problem? The thing is, I cannot upload the document itself (only maybe the empty form), as it contains sensitive financial and personal (address) data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, interestingly enough the problem doesn't seem to be with the document or the PDF printers, but my software! Opening it in and printing it via Acrobat made the problems.

Now when I did print it via Foxit Reader, it worked just fine!
I picked the idea for that up here: http://www.pdfforge.org/forum/help/6024-printing-encrypted-pdf-pdfcreator-fails#comment-6369